# SS_HTTPRequest in SilverStripe

Tags: php, silverstripe

When do we need SS_HTTPRequest as argument to a function in SilverStripe? A tutorial created an action with this:

```
class RegionsPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    private static $allowed_actions = array (
        'show'
    );

    public function show(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

    }

}
```

Comment: As you said... when you have an "action", a method in your controller you can access directly in your browser. See https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.3/developer_guides/controllers/access_control/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a public static method exists in a class, and its name is declared as a value in that classes `$allowed_actions` private static (aka SilverStripe's config system re-purposing private statics in this way) then when that method is called, SS will itself automatically pass an instance of the current `SS_HTTPRequest` object into it.